# Find number of matrix groups

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication, discrete-mathematics

Given:

- number of rows
- number of columns
- maximum value matrix can take

Two matrices are considered equivalent, if one can be obtained from another by swapping rows and columns. Matrices which are equivalent can be grouped together. How to find number of such groups?

Comment: Matrices have no obvious order, so what do you mean by "maximum value matrix can take"? Do you mean the maximum allowed value of the absolute value of an element of the matrix? What kind of elements are they: positive integers, integers, rationals, reals, complex, other? Do you want code that finds the number of such groups or just the number? Most important, what work have you done so far on this problem? Please show your attempted code--that is what this site is all about. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [polya theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) problem. You should learn it and related concepts from wikipedia first, like permutation, cycles and group.

Say number of rows is N, number of columns is M and maximum value matrix can take is V. There are (N+M)! permutations in the group and V colors we can use.

Easy solution would be enumerating over all possible permutation of rows and permutation of columns. Then c(g) can be computed by c(permutation of rows) * c(permutation of columns). This is a O((N + M)!) algorithm.

Advanced solution needs some trick. You can count the number of permutations of rows which has exactly c_row cycles, where 1 <= c_row <= N, and similar for columns. Then you can enumerate over all (c_row, c_column) pairs, and summary the result. This would be a O(N^2 + M^2 + NM) algorithm with proper implementation.

In both case, you would need to use some class like BigInteger in java, as the answer would be very huge.

If I got more time and you did need some code for demonstration, I'll write one later.

Comment: Please do not write code for this question, which is badly stated and shows no effort at all. If the OP improves the question, then and only then would your code be appropriate. And please do not edit and "correct" the question when the OP does not indicate at all which correction is appropriate.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for your advise. It's sure that the OP didn't present this problem in the most clear way. However, such description is actually enough to understand the stuff the OP wants to ask, and the "correction" is a proposal of edition that is intended to be peered reviewed by the OP.